# Error "tcgetpgrp failed: Not a tty" using python3 to open web browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, wsl-2, python-webbrowser

Here's the breakdown of my Windows WSL environment:

- Windows 11
- WSL version 2
- Ubuntu version 20.04.3 LTS
- Python 3.8.10

I have a super simple Python program I'm using to open a web page in my default browser.

Here is my code:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('https://github.com')
```

When I run this from my terminal the webpage opens up as expected, but I also get this error in the terminal:

> `tcgetpgrp failed: Not a tty`

When my terminal displays this message, the cursor goes down to the next line and it looks like a process is hung or something. To be able to use the terminal I have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to get it to give me the command prompt.

I looked for answers and everything I could find has to do with using Jupyter or PHP but I'm not using either of them, I'm just using plain old Python to try and open the browser.

Can anyone tell me what the issue is here and how to fix this/prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, I can also reproduce it from the Python (and IPython) REPL on Ubuntu under WSL.  I don't get the "lockup" that requires <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> when running interactively, at least.

I'll *theorize* on the "why".  Most of this I can confirm myself, but the last bullet below is still a bit of a mystery to me:

- `webbrowser-open` uses whatever browser is defined by the `BROWSER` environment variable first, but falls back to (I believe) `xdg-open`.
- `xdg-open` uses whatever browser is defined in the `alternatives` system for `x-www-browser` or `www-browser`.
- On Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL, the `wslu` package is installed by default (it is no longer a default package under 22.04, though).
- That package includes the `wslview` helper.  From its manpage:

  > [wslview] is a file viewer on WSL that allows you to open files and folders from WSL in Windows and a fake web browser that allows opening urls in your default browser on Windows 10.
- `wslview` is registered during the `wslu` installation as the alternative for both `x-www-browser` and `www-browser`.
- `webbrowser.open` doesn't just *call* `xdg-open`, but it attempts to get the process information of the resulting browser so that it can (at the least) raise the window if requested.  Part of this is obtaining the process group via, apparently, the `tcgetpgrp` system call.  According to the `tcgetpgrp` manpage:

  > The function `tcgetpgrp()` returns the process group ID of the foreground process group on the terminal associated to fd, which must be the controlling terminal of the calling process.
- Here's where I have to "hand-wave" a bit -- *Something* in the hand-off from `webbrowser.open` to `wslview` to `binfmt_misc` (the kernel system that allows it to launch Windows executables) is "losing" or redirecting a file descriptor of the terminal, resulting in this message.

  It *appears* to me to be a bug (unintended side-effect?) of `wslview`, since making sure it isn't used will prevent the error from occurring.

As a workaround, either:

- `export BROWSER=/mnt/c/path/to/windows/browser` before starting Python.  Note that I'm not sure how to point to Edge, since it's there's no ".exe" for it that I'm aware of (it's a Universal/Modern/UWP/whatever app).
- Or, since you are on Windows 11, install a Linux browser.  I used Vivaldi to test and confirm that it opened properly from Python under WSL.  Note that you can't `sudo apt install` either Chromium or Firefox under WSL since they are both Snaps.

Comment: such a great answer! thank you so much for taking the time to explain this in such a clear way. I was able to use the first workaround of exporting the path to my browser executable. After doing that I can run the script with no errors. Marked as accepted and upvoted, thanks again!

Comment: the `export BROWSER=path_to_chrome.exe` worked great for me!! many thanks!

Comment: I had a similar issue, but I had a `DISPLAY` environment variable set from when I was playing with X410 - I also needed to unset this in order to get the browser to listen to the `BROWSER` setting.

Comment: What should the path look like? How do I navigate from my wsl to my windows enviorment with the path? Or do I just use the windows path? Here is what I have: `export BROWSER=C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`

Comment: where should I put this export syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Per the post above I used:

export BROWSER=/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Google/Chrome/Application/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like if you install wslu manually on 22.04+ you can also export BROWSER=/usr/bin/wslview to resolve this.

Comment: where do we put this export?